# How to make a browsers recognize my FIDO2 authenticator?

Tags: webauthn, fido, authenticator

Hi I'm writing my own FIDO2 authenticator implementation. The firmware runs on a SAM E51 Curiosity Nano. I use tinyusb for the communication with the client (raw usb) and can successfully create new credentials and get/verify assertions using the libfido2 suite.

When I try to test my authenticator with one of the WebAuthn test websites (webauthn.io, webauthn.me, ...) using Firefox, the browser seems to ignore the device/ doesn't recognize it.

Do I need to whitelist the device in some way or is there a specific usb configuration required?

I don't really know what to look for.

### dmesg output

#### own

```
new full-speed USB device number 29 using xhci_hcd
[15568.051250] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=cafe, idProduct=4004, bcdDevice= 1.00
[15568.051265] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[15568.051272] usb 1-1: Product: CandyStick FIDO
[15568.051278] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: SugarYourCoffee
[15568.051282] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: cafebabe
[15568.054804] hid-generic 0003:CAFE:4004.0027: hiddev1,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Device [SugarYourCoffee CandyStick FIDO] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
```

#### YubiKey

```
new full-speed USB device number 30 using xhci_hcd
[16832.270596] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1050, idProduct=0407, bcdDevice= 5.12
[16832.270611] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[16832.270618] usb 1-1: Product: YubiKey OTP+FIDO+CCID
[16832.270624] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Yubico
[16832.275477] input: Yubico YubiKey OTP+FIDO+CCID as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:1050:0407.0028/input/input38
[16832.333245] hid-generic 0003:1050:0407.0028: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Yubico YubiKey OTP+FIDO+CCID] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
[16832.334542] hid-generic 0003:1050:0407.0029: hiddev1,hidraw4: USB HID v1.10 Device [Yubico YubiKey OTP+FIDO+CCID] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input1
```

The only difference I see is that the YubiKey can also act as a input device.

I couldn't find anything related to my problem online.

[GITHUB](https://github.com/r4gus/candy-stick)

### Update 06.12.2022

So like I mentioned in a comment below, systems detect possible HID authenticators through the `F1D0` usage page.

One interesting thing is that I'm able to create new credentials for [webauthn.io](https://webauthn.io/) and [webauthn.me](https://webauthn.me/) with Chrome, but not with Firefox. Assertions don't work with either browser (but this seems like a different issue).

CBOR errors, like the wrong order of keys, seem to trigger a warning when using Chrome (something like: old or unsupported authenticator).

I'm really curious why Chrome is able to detect my authenticator and Firefox is not. Unfortunately there is no clear documentation on how both browsers enumerate authenticators. I've started reading through a fork of the Firefox source code, but wasn't able to pinpoint the code that checks for `F1D0` or something similar.

Comment: One thing that I overlooked was that potential CTAPHID devices are identified by the Usage Page `0xF1DO` and a Usage of `0x01`. For tinyusb that means adjusting `HID_USAGE_PAGE_N` in `src/class/hid/hid_device.h`, i.e. copy `TUD_HID_REPORT_DESC_GENERIC_INOUT` and set `HID_USAGE_PAGE_N` to `( 0xF1D0, 2 )`. Now I can discover my authenticator via `fido2-token -L`. Issue with browser still remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that Firefox supports CTAP2 authenticators on non-Windows platforms. You may need to implement U2F (i.e. CTAP1) for Firefox support.

Answer (score 1):

Try now, with Firefox 110 on Linux - It looks like CTAP2 was merged in just recently:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1530373